# Could not load class in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I have the tried to run a java class in eclipse, but every time it sends back this error message. I recently changed the class names, and then git pushed it to a github repo. This error was found is the pull of that pushed repo, on a different computer.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nwTZP.png)

When I also pushed the bin folder from my original file directory, the run worked but used the unchanging .class files from the previous build. Is there anything hidden I need to change the name of for this to work? It works fine on my other setup.

The class definitely has a main method.

Comment: The red exclamation mark at the project folder means that something is preventing the Java code from being compiled. Go to the _Problems_ view for more details.

Comment: can you add here you class structure and main method signature without that it will be difficult to answer your question.

Comment: please format the code correctly

Comment: Hmm. I think I may be missing a library. I'll add it and see if that fixes it.

Comment: The red exclamation mark means something other than just a missing library. The error message is shown in the _Problems_ view and is missing in your question.

Comment: I don't know too much about eclipse, but the problem stated a missing library (MySQL connector/J), and upon installing that the problem seems to have been fixed. I'm not sure how to package the connector straight into my code so that anyone who clones the repo can run the code (my teacher), but this should do for now.

Answer (score -1):

Check eclipse Classpath and check that your gitignore file is not excluding any important files or directories related to your project such as **.class** file or the **bin** folder. Adjust your gitignore file to include these files.

Try to clean up your git repo by using

```
git clean -df
git reset --hard
```

If error occurs again then try to perform a clean build of your project
Right click on your project, go to "Clean" and select your project.

Comment: When I sent the bin folder to git as well, running the program again instead shows only the latest classes created in bin. That is, running the program does not RELOAD the .class files and so any changes done in the .java files do not reflect in the .class files which are used to actually run the code. I'm not sure how to force run to produce new class files, as it does on my usual setup. Even copying and pasting the entire eclipse folder from that setup does not work.